# Efficient Elemental Manland Creation

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I know cards like [Nissa, Worldwaker](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=383328) will get a whole bunch of new lands and make them into Elementals, but are there any way to make all the lands you currently have on the battlefield into Elementals, even for a turn?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want your lands to specifically have the "elemental" creature type:

- [Liege of the Tangle](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Liege%20of%20the%20Tangle)

If you don't care what creature type they are, as long as they're creatures:

- [Jolrael, Empress of Beasts](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Jolrael%2C%20Empress%20of%20Beasts)
- [Life](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Life)
- [Living Plane](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Living%20Plane)
- [Natural Affinity](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Natural%20Affinity)
- [Natural Emergence](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Natural%20Emergence)
- [Nature's Revolt](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=25592)
- [Rude Awakening](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Rude%20Awakening)

If you only need a single type of land to be animated:

- Forests
- [Ambush Commander](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Ambush%20Commander)
- [Living Lands](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Living%20Lands)
- [Thelonite Druid](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Thelonite%20Druid)
- [Life and Limb](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Life%20and%20Limb)
- Swamps
- [Kormus Bell](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Kormus%20Bell)

Comment: Liege of the Tangle is exactly what I was looking for, thanks!